# Does Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise use all available CPU cores during compilation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Does Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise use all available CPU cores during compilation? What if there's only one project in a solution, can it still utilize more than one?

Comment: I don't thunk, that there is any difference between VS editions in this sense. Having parallel compilation for a single project is a hard task. Theoretically, compilation can be parallelized, linking however, not. Not a direct answer, but might be interesting: https://www.google.com/amp/s/sturla.io/load-and-build-solution-faster/amp/

Comment: Depends on your code language.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild – the build tool that .NET (Framework and Core) use will build projects concurrently. Any one project is built (largely) on one thread, but if two projects do not depend on each other they can be built together on different CPUs. A specific compiler may itself be multi-threaded (eg. parsing on one thread and handling reference look ups on another) but that depends on the individual compiler.

This can be controlled in Tools | Options | Projects and Settings | Build and Run.

Other build tools have their own options.

TL;DR: potentially all CPUs but in practice builds are often IO/Memory limited anyway.